# jQuery toggleClass and bootstrap dropdown on hover

Tags: jquery

What I do not understand. I have this function:

```
function dropdown_opened(){
     if ( jQuery('#autocollapse').hasClass('collapsed') ) {
    
     }else{
    
         jQuery('.dropdown').hover(function() {
             jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
             console.log('aaaaa');
         });
     }
}
```

I set it for `windows.resize` event... but even when #autocollapse does have class "collapse" it fires `console.log('aaaaa')`.

What I try to make is a bootstrap dropdown with active dropdown-toggle button state with opened menu - on hover.

What I do wrong? Should I in some way remove hover even?

Comment: But your code says to do the console.log when it doesn't have the class.. what's the problem? if you want it the other way around add ! in your if or put the code of your else into the if brackets and remove the else

Comment: my mistake ... when it DOES have class collapsed it also fired hover event

Comment: is the name of the class "collapsed" or "collapse"

Comment: collapsed. Now I see that problem doesnt exist when I reload page with added collapsed class on start - then hover do not fire.

Comment: You know that as soon as your code enters the else once, the hover event is there forever unless you unbind it.

Comment: no I did not know that, thanks. Now I have other problem but ok, hover stop working when unbind it.